# cake php router

Tags: php, cakephp

while I run the cake php application? Fatal error: Class 'Router' not found in C:\wamp\www\tickerping\app\config\routes.php on line 34 
how to solve this

Comment: i added the cakephp tag so the community actually finds this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file C:\wamp\www\tickerping\cake\libs\router.php exists.  This is the file for the Router class.  If so, I would recommend posting your index.php file so we can see what your path variables are set too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever had Cake running on that server?

Check that mod_rewrite is installed/enabled. You can do this by making a file called phpinfo.php in your webroot containing the line `<?php echo phpinfo.php ?>`. Navigate to that page in the browser and search for 'rewrite'.